# Do ConfigurationManager XML Elements support arrays?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, system.configuration

I’m using Configuration Manager to store settings in a C# application. I have some individual settings and I have a variable array of settings.

The XML Config looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Option" value="Tabbed" />
    <add key="Version" value="0.0.0.0" />
    <Tee1>
      <add key="Name" value="Test1" />
      <add key="IPAddress" value="127.0.0.1" />
      <add key="Port" value="58323" />
      <add key="AutoConnect" value="True" />
      <add key="Link" value="False" />
      <add key="Link" value="False" />
    </Tee1>
    <Tee2>
      <add key="Name" value="Test2" />
      <add key="IPAddress" value="127.0.0.1" />
      <add key="Port" value="58324" />
      <add key="AutoConnect" value="True" />
      <add key="Link" value="False" />
      <add key="Link" value="False" />
    </Tee2>
    <Tee3>
      <add key="Name" value="Test3" />
      <add key="IPAddress" value="localhost" />
      <add key="Port" value="58325" />
      <add key="AutoConnect" value="False" />
      <add key="Link" value="True" />
      <add key="Link" value="False" />
    </Tee3>
    <Tee4 />
    <Tee5 />
    <Tee6 />
    <Tee7 />
    <Tee8 />
    <Tee9 />
    <Tee10>
      <add key="Name" value="Test10" />
      <add key="IPAddress" value="127.0.0.1" />
      <add key="Port" value="58332" />
      <add key="AutoConnect" value="False" />
      <add key="Link" value="False" />
      <add key="Link" value="False" />
    </Tee10>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The Tee entries without data are null items.

When I load the generated XML text into the Visual Studio 2010 editor it shows TEE1 has an error.

*“The element ‘appSettings’ has an invalid child element ‘Tee1’. List of possible elements expected: ‘add, remove. Clear’.”*

How should I represent an array of similar items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only store `key=value` settings in `<appSettings>`. If you want something richer, you'll need to write a custom configuration section handler.

See, for example:

- [How to: Create Custom Configuration Sections Using ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx)
- [Custom Configuration Sections in 3 Easy Steps](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/12/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx)
- [.NET Custom Configuration Section, Collection and Elements](http://jokecamp.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/net-custom-configuration-section-collection-and-elements/)